# How to add new users in jbpm-console deployed on tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat7, drools, jbpm, kie-workbench

I'm trying to deploy the jbpm-console with jbpm 6.2 on tomcat 7. I made all necessary settings described in the README(https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions/blob/master/kie-wb/kie-wb-distribution-wars/src/main/assembly/tomcat7/README.txt).

That done, I can log into the system with the default users (admin, analyst, developer ..), but when I log with new users, I logged in as anonymous. It seems to me that I need to add these users in the application also.

In Wildfly 8.1.0.Final of the jbpm-installer is available the add-user.sh (in the bin folder) to add users in the application. But how can I do this for the tomcat 7?

Answer (score 3):

Go to jbpm-installer -> wildfly-8.1.0.Final -> standalone -> configuration There you will find users.properties you can add user and u need to assign roles to the user you created.

```
 Then stop demo and start again. Sure it will work
```

Answer (score 0):

The JBPM console uses the containers JAAS module for user management. For tomcat, that is controlled by the tomcat-users.xml file. Look [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=949) for an exaple.